# Accessing StringProperty from .py file to TextInput in .kv file

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to kivy.
I want to set the text of StringProperty to TextInput in .kv file. So that it get displayed in GUI.

Suppose, i have -

.py file

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '200')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import StringProperty,ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

import speech_recognition as sr
import sys
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
import json


r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone()

class Root(BoxLayout):
    pass
class RecordButton(Button):
    # String Property to Hold output for publishing by Textinput
    output = StringProperty('')

    def record(self):
        # GUI Blocking Audio Capture
        with m as source:
            audio = r.listen(source)

        try:
            # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
            value = r.recognize_google(audio)
            self.output = "You said \"{}\"".format(value)

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            self.output = ("Oops! Didn't catch that")

        except sr.RequestError as e:
            self.output = ("Uh oh! Couldn't request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))


class SpeechApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Calibrate the Microphone to Silent Levels
        print("A moment of silence, please...")
        with m as source:
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            print("Set minimum energy threshold to {}".format(r.energy_threshold))
        # Create a root widget object and return as root
        return Root()

class GrammarButton(Button):
    output_obj = ObjectProperty(None)
    grammar_button = ObjectProperty(None)

    """Colored text class"""
    colors = ['black', 'red', 'green', 'orange', 'blue', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'white']
    color_dict = {}
    for i, c in enumerate(colors):
        color_dict[c] = (i + 30, i + 40)

    @classmethod
    def colorize(cls, text, color=None, bgcolor=None):
        """Colorize text
        @param cls Class
        @param text Text
        @param color Text color
        @param bgcolor Background color
        """
        c = None
        bg = None
        gap = 0
        if color is not None:
            try:
                c = cls.color_dict[color][0]
            except KeyError:
                print("Invalid text color:", color)
                return(text, gap)

        if bgcolor is not None:
            try:
                bg = cls.color_dict[bgcolor][1]
            except KeyError:
                print("Invalid background color:", bgcolor)
                return(text, gap)

        s_open, s_close = '', ''
        if c is not None:
            s_open = '\033[%dm' % c
            gap = len(s_open)
        if bg is not None:
            s_open += '\033[%dm' % bg
            gap = len(s_open)
        if not c is None or bg is None:
            s_close = '\033[0m'
            gap += len(s_close)
        return('%s%s%s' % (s_open, text, s_close), gap)


    def get_ginger_url(self,text):
        """Get URL for checking grammar using Ginger.
        @param text English text
        @return URL
        """
        API_KEY = "6ae0c3a0-afdc-4532-a810-82ded0054236"

        scheme = "http"
        netloc = "services.gingersoftware.com"
        path = "/Ginger/correct/json/GingerTheText"
        params = ""
        query = urllib.parse.urlencode([
            ("lang", "US"),
            ("clientVersion", "2.0"),
            ("apiKey", API_KEY),
            ("text", text)])
        fragment = ""

        return(urllib.parse.urlunparse((scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment)))


    def get_ginger_result(self,text):
        """Get a result of checking grammar.
        @param text English text
        @return result of grammar check by Ginger
        """
        url = GrammarButton.get_ginger_url(self,text)

        try:
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        except HTTPError as e:
                print("HTTP Error:", e.code)
                quit()
        except URLError as e:
                print("URL Error:", e.reason)
                quit()

        try:
            result = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
        except ValueError:
            print("Value Error: Invalid server response.")
            quit()

        return(result)


    def main(self):
        """main function"""
        output_obj = RecordButton()
        original_text = output_obj.output
        if len(original_text) > 600:
            print("You can't check more than 600 characters at a time.")
            quit()
        fixed_text = original_text
        results = GrammarButton.get_ginger_result(self,original_text)


        # Correct grammar
        if(not results["LightGingerTheTextResult"]):
            print("Good English :)")
            quit()

        # Incorrect grammar
        color_gap, fixed_gap = 0, 0
        for result in results["LightGingerTheTextResult"]:
            if(result["Suggestions"]):
                from_index = result["From"] + color_gap
                to_index = result["To"] + 1 + color_gap
                suggest = result["Suggestions"][0]["Text"]

                # Colorize text
                colored_incorrect = GrammarButton.colorize(original_text[from_index:to_index], 'red')[0]
                colored_suggest, gap = GrammarButton.colorize(suggest, 'green')

                original_text = original_text[:from_index] + colored_incorrect + original_text[to_index:]
                fixed_text = fixed_text[:from_index-fixed_gap] + colored_suggest + fixed_text[to_index-fixed_gap:]

                color_gap += gap
                fixed_gap += to_index-from_index-len(suggest)


        print("from: " + original_text)
        print("to:   " + fixed_text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SpeechApp().run()
    #main()
```

.kv file

```
    #:kivy 1.0.9

<Root>:
    text1 : text1
    orientation: 'vertical'
    RecordButton:
        id: record_button
        text: 'Record Speech'
        on_release: self.record()
        height: '50dp'
        size_hint_y: None

    TextInput:
        text: record_button.output
        readonly: True


    GrammarButton:
        id: grammar_button
        text: 'Check Grammar'
        on_release : self.main()
        height: '50dp'
        size_hint_y: None

    TextInput:
        id : text1  
        text : grammar_button.fixed_text or ??? - what to write here so that I will get desired results
        readonly: True
```

[I want that console output in GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM61K.png)

Please help me to solve this.I am done with all the solutions that I know or get to know as per my understandings. I am confused now.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is class A a Kivy class?

Comment: I have Button named 'A'.Sorry I didn't specified it earlier

Comment: Does the kv file belongs to another class?

Comment: @ikolim Please have a look. I have also added the image which may give better understanding of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never assign the results of `get_ginger_result()` to a StringProperty so you'll need to add one then assign the desired value. Then you can reference it in the kv code.

You might add this to your GrammarButton class:

```
class GrammarButton(Button):
    suggestion = StringProperty()
    output_obj = ObjectProperty(None)
    grammar_button = ObjectProperty(None)

def main(self):
    ...
    self.suggestion = fixed_text
```

And then you can reference it this way:

```
TextInput:
    id: text1  
    text: grammar_button.suggestion
    readonly: True
```